# Get to know whether a cell is inside a range

Tags: vba, match

I'm trying to make a code which does something if a cell is in a range, i've tried this:

```
For i = 1 To lastrow
If Not IsEmpty(wsdata.Cells(i, 3)) And Not IsEmpty(wsdata.Cells(i, 4)) Then
    If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(range("ISINS").Value, Cell(i,3) Then
        MsgBox ("Not in the list")
    Else
    MsgBox ("In the list")
    End If
End If
Next i
```

But obviously did not work! I've also tried with the Interest function like this:

```
If Intersect(range("ISINS"),Cells(i,3)) Is Nothing Then
```

it runs but it doesn't find any value that isn't in the range however there are!
I created a range so that i don't use Cells, but the error remains.
ISINS is juste the name of my range in excel, it could also be A:A.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe look at the names refer to range `names("testname").RefersToRange`

Comment: Why don't you share the complete code or at least from `Sub` to `Next i`? What are the error number and error description? If you want to use `Match` you have to make sure that the range is either one column or one row. The better and correct way is to use something like `If IsError(Application.Match(wsData(Cells(i, 3)).Value, Range("ISINS"), 0)) Then` meaning that the value in `.Cells(i, 3)` was not found in `ISINS`. Share your complete code to get a useful answer. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72517133/edit) at any time.

Comment: I was only struggling with this part of the code so it made no sense to me to share the whole code. Thank you for your help, it's working now! Since I have around 250 rows, should I use Match or Intercept, which one would be faster in this case?

Comment: I still don't exactly know what you need to do. `Cell(i,3)` at the end of the match line cannot possibly work without the missing `s` and the closing parentheses. If you're trying to find a value in `ISINS`, then `Intersect` has nothing to do with it. On the other hand, if you're trying to determine if the cell `Cells(i, 3)` is a cell of `ISINS`, then `Match` has nothing to do with it. Also, previously I wrote a wrong line; it should be `If IsError(Application.Match(wsData.Cells(i, 3).Value, Range("ISINS"), 0)) Then`.